Spark broadcasting and race condition
in my spark streaming application, I am managing a variable in my driver node and am broadcasting that variable to all executors before executing readStream(…)
But I have a requirement to update the broadcast variable when an event occurs in the driver node. To achieve this I’n performing an unpersist() on the old broadcast value and subsequently broadcasting the new value.
So my question, I'm wondering if this will result in a race condition where the function "func" below (executed in the executor) retrieves an unperisted broadcast variable? And if so, how can i fix it? Thank you!
It looks somewhat like this
// Lives on the Driver Node
public class BroadcastWrapper {
    Broadcast<List<String>> broadcastVar;
    List<String> ls;
    JavaSparkContext jsc;

    public BroadcastWrapper(JavaSparkContext jsc) {
        this.jsc = jsc;
        this.ls = new ArrayList<>();
        this.ls.add(“hello”);
        this.broadcastVar = jsc.broadcast(ls);
   }

   public void addAndupdate(String s) {
       this.ls.add(s);
       this.broadcastVar.unpersist();
       this.broadcastVar = this.jsc.broadcast(this.ls);
   }
}

And in my Driver class, I will be doing something like this
// JavaSparkContext initialised before 
BroadcastWrapper broadcastWrapper = new BroadcastWrapper(javaSparkContext);
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.readStream(…);

// func internally calls broadcastWrapper.broadcastVar.value to retrieve the value or list
ds.map(data -> func(broadcastWrapper));

